# Are SQL tuples, when used as predicates, just a syntactic sugar for expanded logical AND's?

Tags: sql, db2

Are SQL tuples, when used as predicates, just a syntactic sugar for expanded logical AND's or there is more to it?

eg.

```sql
with tmp1(c1,c2,c3) as (
  select * from (
    values(1,'a','apple')
    ,(2,'b','ball')
    ,(3,'c','cat')
    ,(4,'d','dog')
    ,(5,'e',null)
  )
)
select * from tmp1 where (c1,c2,c3) = (1,'a','apple');
```

is equivalent to

```sql
select * from tmp1 where c1 = 1 and c2 = 'a' and c3 = 'apple';
```

and similarly for IN clause or JOIN's

I did check for NULL awareness(if it would get translated to the form x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y) but atleast DB2 isn't

```sql
select * from tmp1 where (c1,c2,c3) = (5,'e',null); -- Empty resultset
```

Comment: Well it is much more than syntactical sugar for me specially when used with subselects. It is extremely useful and much shorter when used i.e. WHERE (c1, c2) in (SELECT col1, col2 from xy where ...). For NULL remember nothing compares to NULL - this means no value will be equal NULL.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher Aha! I missed this point. About NULL awareness I was thinking if it would get translated to a form like x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y and hence that it bring a difference but probably that wasn't the way it worked.

Comment: Look at the [Basic predicate](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=predicates-basic-predicate) description in the db2 docs, `Table 3` about `row-value-expressions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are strictly considering scalar equality, yes, it's equivalent.

There are other not-so-simple cases:

- When you consider predicates with a set operator like `IN` or `NOT IN` then it's a more powerful construct, as in:

  ```
  (a, b, c) in (select x, y, z...)
  (a, b, c) not in (select x, y, z...)
  ```
- When the predicate includes a *tuple inequality*. This is specially useful in query pagination. For example:

  ```
  (a, b, c) >= (x, y, z)
  ```

  without tuples it the syntax would be much more verbose, as in:

  ```
  a > x OR a = x AND (b > y OR b = y AND c >= z)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I definitely missed these aspects.

Comment: Your 2-nd rewritten expression is not equivalent to the original one - wrong braces placement. It may be `(a > x OR a = x) AND (b > y OR b = y) AND c >= z`, if you prefer a longer form of simpler `a >= x AND b >= y AND c >= z`.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Tuple inequalities work like version numbers. For example, `1.6.2` is greater than `1.5.8` even though `2` is less than `8`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and my comment is not. Sorry for that.